# Is there a way to specify a default value for the name property of a Chef resource?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Ideally, I would like to be able to do:

```
resource_name :house

property :material, String, default: 'brick', name_property: true
...
```

so that I could then do

```
house do
  ...
end
```

and material property would be set to `'brick'`, but this results in the error message:

`A property cannot be both a name_property/name_attribute and have a default value ...`

which is clear enough. I am reasonably certain what I am asking for is not possible, but, I might also be missing an alternative way of achieving the same, so I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would have to do it at the name level itself. See https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/resource/apt_update.rb#L31.

This should be used very very sparingly, it's pretty rare for something to be a true global singleton.